# Doing wp_set_object_terms on a wordpress post causes duplicate posts to be made?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making a wordpress post via the following code:

```
    $data = array();
    $data['post_title'] = $this->title;
    $data['post_content'] = $this->desc;
    $data['post_status'] = 'published';
    $data['post_type'] = 'product';

    $this->id = wp_insert_post($data);

    add_post_meta($this->id, "foo", $this->foo);
    add_post_meta($this->id, "bar", $this->bar);
```

After doing this, I then try to set the taxonomy terms for the post.

I have one taxonomy called "foo", and I have 10-12 terms created in wp_terms table. Before making the post, I have retrieved the term_id of the term that I want to use, and I already know that the taxonomy is foo. So, I do the following:

```
//termId has already been retrieved from the wp_terms table
wp_set_object_terms($this->id, $this->termId, "foo" );
```

When I do this, then sometimes, for some posts, a duplicate post is randomly made. This is done within wordpress's code, and isn't done by my code.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this error was being caused because my plugin was doing all this on the `init` hook. It seems that setting the terms sometimes instantiated a new request, which triggered the init action twice, causing my plugin to run again, and become stuck in infinite recursion.

Switching to `parse_request` hook, and listening for a `$_GET` variable for doing the processing, fixed the issue.